# Error on the get text searchview in actionbar

Tags: android, searchview

I want get text of search view that is in the action bar.I use this code, but the app don't run and show error message: Unreachable code.
what is my mistake?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.collection__list_, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        /// ****
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_collection);
        SearchView word_search_collection = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        word_search_collection.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling "return" on the 2nd line of method. So the code below it will never execute and because of this Java can't compile :)

Move return statement to the end of method.

Answer (score 1):

You should move second line to end of the function.
Otherwise this program not works like you want.
return function must be end of functions. Maybe you didn't see it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` It is only `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`